# Problem in understanding Normalization in inequalities

Tags: inequality, contest-math

To clarify my doubt lets take an example

> Let $a, b, c$ be non-negative real numbers. Prove that
>   $$
> \sqrt{\frac{a b+b c+c a}{3}} \leq \sqrt[3]{\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}}
> $$

now let $a^{\prime}=\frac{a}{t}, b^{\prime}=\frac{b}{t}, c^{\prime}=\frac{c}{t}(t>0) .$ The inequality is true for $a, b, c$ if and only if it's true for $a^{\prime}, b^{\prime}, c^{\prime} .$ If we plug those values in, we will realize that nothing is changed in the original inequality...so we can let $t$ be anything positive.

so $a^{\prime}+b^{\prime}+c^{\prime} = (a+b+c) / t$

so we can take $t=(a+b+c)/3$ then we get $a^{\prime}+b^{\prime}+c^{\prime}=3$

but if we take $t=a+b+c$ then we get $a^{\prime}+b^{\prime}+c^{\prime}=1$

**How this can be possible that is we get two values of a+b+c ???**

Comment: Check my new answer.

Comment: The whole point of normalisation is that, since $a+b+c=$ is not constant in general, (i.e. it can take on a range of values), you want to intentionally impose the condition that $a+b+c=1$, which is perfectly valid since it does not change the inequality at all. To claim that $a+b+c=3$ is always true is wrong, as illustrated by the $2$ examples I have provided. Rather, it is more accurate for you to think of it as a restriction of the sum $a+b+c$ to $3$ which still preserves the inequality ( anyways this is pointless since your goal is to normalise the sum to $1$).

Comment: Which preserves the inequality too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a+b+c=3t$. Let $a=ta'$, $b=tb'$ and $c=tc'$. This implies $a'+b'+c'=3$, and our given inequality can easily be checked to be the same as before, so the restriction $a+b+c=3$ does not change anything of the inequality.

On the other hand, you can be completely arbitrary and let $a=3a't, b=3b't, c=3c't$. Then this implies $a'+b'+c'=1$, so the restriction $a+b+c=1$ does not change anything, either.

The main idea of normalization is to either restrict the variables to like $a+b+c=1$, or either $abc=1$. So it's not wrong to have $a+b+c=3$, but you could as well have $a+b+c=1$.

Comment: ok,one last thing - how we will come to know that which restriction on variables will solve our inequality ??? because there are so many choices.

Comment: There is unfortunately no definitive answer to this question. Obviously there would be a few approaches that work, but I guess knowing how to do the right thing is something that comes with experience of doing more problems.

Comment: ok,thanks a lot for giving your time....